# Why does Fsharp Interactive allow mutable variables to be captured by closures?

Tags: f#, closures, mutable, f#-interactive

Using an example from Chris Smith's *Programming F# 3.0*:

```
let invalidUseOfMutable() =
    let mutable x = 0
    let incrementX() = x <- x + 1
    incrementX()
    x;;
```

This fails as expected:

> error FS0407: The mutable variable 'x' is used in an invalid way.
>   Mutable variables cannot be captured by closures.

Now cut and paste the body of the function into FSharp Interactive:

```
let mutable x = 0
let incrementX() = x <- x + 1
incrementX()
x;;
```

And it works!

> val it : int = 1

Why?

Comment: Hi, it does not generate closure when you just run the body code.use: let x = ref 0; let incrementX() = x := !x + 1;see Closures:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233186.aspx

Comment: Note that the compiler also doesn't object to the body of the function on its own.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Edit:** the following answer is correct for F# up to 3.x. Starting with F# 4.0, local mutables are automatically converted into `ref`s if needed, so OP's code will actually successfully compile in all cases.

---

Short answer: it's not because of `fsi`, it's because the mutable is global.

Long answer:

For a normal (non-mutable) capture, implementation-wise the captured value is copied into the function object, so that if you return this function and use it outside of the scope in which it has been defined, everything works fine.

```
let pureAddOne() =
    let x = 1
    let f y = x + y    // the value 1 is copied into the function object
    f

let g = pureAddOne()
g 3    // x is now out of scope, but its value has been copied and can be used
```

On the other hand, in order to capture a mutable, the capture needs to be done by reference, else you wouldn't be able to modify it. But this is impossible, because in the previously mentioned case where the closure is returned and used outside of its definition scope, the mutable is also out of scope and potentially deallocated. This is the reason for the initial limitation.

```
let mutableAddOne() =
    let mutable x = 1
    let f y = x <- x + y    // x would be referenced, not copied
    f

let g = mutableAddOne()
g 3    // x is now out of scope, so the reference is invalid!
       // mutableAddOne doesn't compile, because if it did, then this would fail.
```

However, if the mutable is global, then there is no such scope issue, and the compiler accepts it. It's not just `fsi`; if you try to compile the following program with `fsc`, it works:

```
module Working

let mutable x = 1    // x is global, so it never goes out of scope

let mutableAddOne() =
    let f y = x <- x + y    // referencing a global. No problem!
    f

let g = mutableAddOne()
g 3    // works as expected!
```

In conclusion, as kwingho said, if you want to have a closure that captures a local mutable value, use a `ref`. They are heap-allocated (as opposed to the stack-allocated local mutable) so as long as the closure holds a reference to it, it won't be deallocated.

Comment: Some important points (for me): "use a `ref`... [for capturing local mutable]..." and "F# (from 4.0) converts automatically `mutable` to `ref`.

So the code always work from F# 4.0.